# Radius Variable Isn't Being Passed From Constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm supposed to be using a constructor to accept the radius of a circle as an argument then using various accessor and mutator methods to display the area, circumference, and diameter. When I input the value for radius, say 4, it says that the radius and all other values (area, circumference, diameter ) are 0.0. I'm new to java and wanna know what I'm missing.

```
// import scanner to read keyboard input
import java.util.Scanner;

class CircleCalculator
{
    private double radius;

    public CircleCalculator(double r)
    {
        radius = r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // declare the variable keyboard that can reference an object of the scanner class 
        // create a new Scanner object in the memory that reads from the input System.in
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to Cam's Magic Circle Calculator!");
        System.out.println("\nEnter the radius of your circle");
        
        double r, a, d, c;

        CircleData circledata = new CircleData();

        System.out.println("\nThe measurements of a circle with the radius " + circledata.getRadius() + " are:\n" +
                    "\tArea: " + circledata.getArea() +" units squared\n" +
                    "\tDiameter: " + circledata.getDiameter() +" units\n" +
                    "\tCircumference: " + circledata.getCircumference() +" units\n");
    }

    public static class CircleData //create class for mutator and accessor methods
    {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double r = keyboard.nextDouble();
    CircleCalculator setRadius = new CircleCalculator(r);

        final double pi = 3.1415;

        private double radius, area, diameter, circumference;

        private double getRadius()
        {
        return radius;
        }

        private double getArea()
        {
        area = pi * radius * radius;
        return area;
        }

        private double getDiameter()
        {
        diameter = 2 * radius;
        return diameter;
        }

        private double getCircumference()
        {
        circumference = 2 * pi * radius;
        return circumference;
        }
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
Welcome to Cam's Magic Circle Calculator!

Enter the radius of your circle
4

The measurements of a circle with the radius 0.0 are:
        Area: 0.0 units squared
        Diameter: 0.0 units
        Circumference: 0.0 units
```

Comment: Seems to me you're confusing `CircleCalculator.radius` with `CircleData.radius`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is confused because of the nesting of your classes. I recommend following good code practices by separating them out into their own class files. Let `CircleData` handle the actual circle data and calculation and make `CircleCalculator` your overall program sequence logic.

**CircleCalculator**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CircleCalculator
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
      System.out.println("\nWelcome to Cam's Magic Circle Calculator!");
      System.out.println("\nEnter the radius of your circle");
      
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      CircleData circledata = new CircleData(keyboard.nextDouble());
      keyboard.close();

      System.out.println("\nThe measurements of a circle with the radius " + circledata.getRadius() + " are:\n" +
                  "\tArea: " + circledata.getArea() +" units squared\n" +
                  "\tDiameter: " + circledata.getDiameter() +" units\n" +
                  "\tCircumference: " + circledata.getCircumference() +" units\n");
  }
}
```

**CircleData** (in separate file so methods are now public)

```
public class CircleData
{
  final double pi = 3.1415;

  private double radius, area, diameter, circumference;
  
  public CircleData(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }

  public double getRadius()
  {
  return radius;
  }

  public double getArea()
  {
  area = pi * radius * radius;
  return area;
  }

  public double getDiameter()
  {
  diameter = 2 * radius;
  return diameter;
  }

  public double getCircumference()
  {
  circumference = 2 * pi * radius;
  return circumference;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Because radius fields from `CircleCalculator` and `CircleData` classes are two different fields. So, you cannot use the radius of `CircleCalculator` from `CircleData` because `CircleData` contains such field already.
2. `CircleData` actually shouldn't have the `Scanner` field, it breaks SRP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle.

I'd recommend writing it this way:

```
class CircleCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare the variable keyboard that can reference an object of the scanner class
        // create a new Scanner object in the memory that reads from the input System.in
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to Cam's Magic Circle Calculator!");
        System.out.println("\nEnter the radius of your circle");
        CircleData circledata = new CircleData(keyboard.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("\nThe measurements of a circle with the radius " + circledata.getRadius() + " are:\n" +
                "\tArea: " + circledata.getArea() + " units squared\n" +
                "\tDiameter: " + circledata.getDiameter() + " units\n" +
                "\tCircumference: " + circledata.getCircumference() + " units\n");
    }

    public static class CircleData //create class for mutator and accessor methods
    {

        final double pi = 3.1415;

        private final double radius;

        public CircleData(double radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        private double getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        private double getArea() {
            return pi * radius * radius;
        }

        private double getDiameter() {
            return 2 * radius;
        }

        private double getCircumference() {
            return 2 * pi * radius;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The radius variable isn't being passed from constructor because you have defined the constructor in the `CircleCalculator` class but the methods for calculating the area, circumference, etc using the radius variable value are in different class.

`CircleCalculator setRadius = new CircleCalculator(r);`
Here, though `setRadius` has the value which user has entered but it's not being used.

`CircleData circledata = new CircleData();`
Here, the circledata is referencing nothing. The method calls
`circledata.getRadius() , circledata.getArea() , circledata.getDiameter() , circledata.getCircumference()`  are actually returning the default value of double that is 0.0 because the `radius` variable default value is 0.0

Also, there should be only one public class in a class file whose name should match the class file name and that public class should have the `public static void main(String[] args)` method.